# foreach inside foreach how can i call the variables

Tags: php, foreach

How can I prevent the value of $key in first loop but I need to call the $key in the second loop?
The value of $key in 1st loop is different to the 2nd loop

```
<?php
$variables = array('ABC' => array('A', 'B', 'C'), 'DEF' => array('D', 'E'));
foreach ($variables as $key => $values){
      echo $key; //the value of $key in first loop is different to the second loop
      foreach($values as $value){
           echo $key; //I want the value of $key is still the value in first loop
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors is it giving you now?

Comment: You just want a name? How about `$key2` and `$yippie`

Comment: (Also you named the first one $value, but used it as $values)

Comment: the value of $key in first loop is different to the second loop

Comment: I changed my codes and question to easily understand my problem. thanks

Comment: No, the value of `$key` is the same in both loops. And I'm confused about what you need to _prevent_.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
<?php
$variables = array('ABC' => array('A', 'B', 'C'), 'DEF' => array('D', 'E'));
foreach ($variables as $key => $values){
    foreach($values as $value){
        // Here you can access every variables previously declared
        echo '<div id='$key' class='$value'>test</div><br />';
    }
}
```

What you were trying to do is to access a variable that you were only declaring later (in the foreach loop). Keep in mind that you can access a variable if it's in the same environment.

Comment: yeah but the value of $key in first loop is different to the second loop

Comment: What do you mean? As you are not declaring another value for $key in your second loop, $key stays the same in the second. Maybe you have some more code that you didn't give?

Comment: I changed my codes to easily understand my problem. Bythe way thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of our reply as being the solution of your problem!

Comment: ok..sory this is my first time to ask a question here in stackoverflow.. so any suggestion in my problem?

Answer (score 0):

without much information in your code i assume you are trying to do this:

```
<?php
$variables = array('ABC' => array('A', 'B', 'C'), 'DEF' => array('D', 'E'));
foreach ($variables as $key => $values){
      foreach($values as $value){
          echo "<div id='$key' class='$value'>test</div><br />";
      }
}
?>
```

Will give you $value and $key both in echo.

Comment: yeah but the value of $key in first loop is different to the second loop

Comment: I changed my codes and question to easily understand my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line has problems:

```
echo '<div id='$key' class='$value'>test</div><br />';
```

1. Variables are not parsed inside single quoted strings. Use double quotes or concatenate.
2. Using single quotes to begin and end the string is a problem when you also use single quotes within the string to define attributes. Escape the quotes or use a combination of double and single.
3. `$value` does not exist at this point. It isn't defined until the line below with the foreach.

Comment: yeah but the value of $key in first loop is different to the second loop

Comment: I changed my codes and question to easily understand my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current code is working fine. I don't see any problems with it.

Comment: How can I prevent the value of $key in first loop but I need to call the $key in the second loop?

Comment: What do you mean by 'prevent the value of $key'?

Comment: in my given codes in first loop the value of $key is 'ABC' and 'DEF' but when I call it in the second loop of foreach the value of $key will changed.

Comment: It won't change just ran that code, it will print "ABCABCABCABCDEFDEFDEF" - 4x (1 outer loop,3x inner loop) ABC and 3x (1 outer loop,2x inner loop)DEF. I still don't see your problem.